# What is "file:" relative to in webapp?

Tags: java

I have a component in my *webapp* which uses something like `file:images/lol.png` . What is the file relative to? WEB-INF directory? I need to put images under `WEB-INF/images` or where?It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Provide the code rather than a description of the code please.

Answer (score 1):

It's relative to the current directory in effect when the webapp server program was started, which means that it's likely a value that's meaningless to you, and you should never use relative file access.

To get a file from the `WEB-INF` directory, use [`ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/images/lol.png")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I am using an external component  component. Cant provide code, cant do much about it. Its said they use relative paths for creating PDF.

Comment: @repo Well, `file:images/lol.png` is a URL in text form, and `getResource()` returns a URL which can be converted to text using [`URL.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toString%28%29), so if the library you're using needs a text URL, then it should work.

Comment: I managed the relative path root is C:\tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin\ 
Thats not cool because i want to get to the context.I have trouble injecting the context ServletContext is not initialized when using @Autowired meh